# Arrays (some keys with arrays, some singular)

Tags: php, arrays

Whilst developing a php class i have run into a rather interesting thing within php. If i was to create a array, some single keys and some with arrays within that key, it only echos numbers rather than the arrays key. Why is that and how do i fix it?

```
<?php

    $example = array('name' => array('required' => true), 'email');

    foreach($example as $field => $value) {
        echo $field;
    }

?>
```

This returns **name0** rather than **nameemail**

Comment: That's because `email` is a value, not a key. Your array actually looks like `Array('name' => Array, 0 => 'email')`.

Comment: use is_array to tell if you need to call recursively or simply print

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you probably want this ::

```
<?php

    $example = array('name' => array('required' => true), 'email');

    foreach($example as $field => $value) {
        if(is_array($value)){
          echo $field;
        }else{
          echo $value;
        }
    }

?>
```

Comment: Thanks, i cant belive how silly my mistakes are at times :)

Answer (score 0):

Because you didn't define a key for the element 'email'. If you would have done this:

```
$example = array('name' => array('required' => true), 'email' => 'something@isp.com');
```

You would have gotten:

```
name email
```

You could have also done this:

```
$example = array('name' => array('required' => true), 'email' => '');
```

And not have had to define a value for the 'email' element.

Answer (score 0):

i guess that "email" is not a key but an element. So strictly the array keys are "name", 0.

If u want to display nameemail

```
<?php

    $example = array('name' => array('required' => true), 'email'=>array());

    foreach($example as $field => $value) {
        echo $field;
    }

?>
```

Comment: Checking if each value is an array like @Pheonix stated would be more beneifical whilst creating a class as it doesnt require the need to create empty arrays but thanks alot for the idea.